# Comparison of date in PowerShell in commands

Tags: powershell

I am using get child item to get file , i want to get file which last modified date/created date matches today's date

```
PS E:\> Get-Childitem –Path 'E:\utility\sysout' -Include *DBA_M_MNT_BACKUP_system* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

output iam getting

```
    Directory: E:\utility\sysout


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         2/16/2018   2:00 AM       4709 TEDM_DBA_M_MNT_BACKUP_System_Databases_021620180200AM.txt
```

i want to see lastwritetime i want date to match with current date 
like `get-date.day`
`get-date.month`
`get-date.year` i need to pick up separate is there way i can compare directly lastwritetime (only date) with current date
and give output of command only when date matches current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed there's a way. Are you looking for something like this -

```
$File = Get-Childitem –Path 'E:\utility\sysout' -Include *DBA_M_MNT_BACKUP_system* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$timediff = (Get-Date) - $File.LastWriteTime
```

You can access the time difference using `$timediff.Days`, `$timediff.Hours` etc. The above works when you get only one file as output. But if you get multiple files in `$File`, then you would want to use it like `$File[0].LastWriteTime`, `$File[1].LastWriteTime`, `$File[2].LastWriteTime` etc. Or you can simply use a `Foreach` loop, whatever suits you depending on your requirement.

Comment: i used something like this because i want to compare year month and date i dont have to take time $File=Get-Childitem –Path 'E:\utility\sysout' -Include *DBA_M_MNT_BACKUP_system* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$timediffyear = (Get-Date).year - $File.LastWriteTime.year
$timediffmonth = (Get-Date).month - $File.LastWriteTime.month

write-host $timediff

write-host $timediffmonth,  for time difference in months its not showing anything i want to simply display filename if lastwritetime matches current date else error

Comment: `(Get-Date).Month - ($File.LastWriteTime).Month` should return you the month difference. It will return `0` if there's no difference.

Comment: $File=Get-Childitem –Path 'E:\utility\sysout' -Include *DBA_M_MNT_BACKUP_system* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$timediffyear = (Get-Date).year - $File.LastWriteTime.year
$timediffmonth = (Get-Date).month - ($File.LastWriteTime).month

write-host $timediff

write-host $timediffmonth  output  PS E:\> e:\utility\example.ps1

0 not showing month difference

Comment: finally got  answer did time diff and checked $File=Get-Childitem –Path 'E:\utility\sysout' -Include *DBA_M_MNT_BACKUP_system* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$timediffyear = (Get-Date).year - $File.LastWriteTime.year
$timediffmonth = (Get-Date).month - ($File.LastWriteTime).month
$timediffday = (Get-Date).day - ($File.LastWriteTime).day

write-host $timediffyear
write-host $timediffmonth
write-host $timediffday

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp |
    Where-Object {
        $_.LastWriteTime -ge ((Get-Date).Date) -and
        $_.LastWriteTime -lt ((Get-Date).Date).AddDays(+1)
    }
```

## How does this work?

Well it sees if the `LastWriteTime` is greater-than the "start of" today, and the "start of" tomorrow, where "start of" is a time of `00:00:00`

### Illustration

```
Write-Host (Get-Date)
Write-Host (Get-Date).Date
Write-Host ((Get-Date).Date).AddDays(+1)
```

### Results

```
16/02/2018 08:03:08
16/02/2018 00:00:00
17/02/2018 00:00:00
```